# systemd vs cgroups for resource isolation by user program?

Tags: kubuntu, google-chrome, cgroup

**Environment**: kubuntu desktop 17.10.1

**Immediate goal**: run `chrome` in such a way as to limit its maximum memory consumption.

**Current workaround**: I put the following in `/usr/local/bin/cchrome`:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo mkdir -p /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/chrome
sudo chown -R ji /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/chrome
echo 8G > /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/chrome/memory.limit_in_bytes
exec cgexec -g memory:chrome google-chrome
```

I then edit my applications menu to create an entry called cchrome, and things are great! If I were less lazy, I would even had created the cgroup at startup so I wouldn't have to invoke sudo in the script.

This works, but it's ugly. According to TFM (`man cgrules.conf` and `man cgconfig.conf`), I should be able to set things up so that when chrome starts up, it runs in its own cgroup. However, these files do not exist in 17.10 desktop or 16.04 LTS server. AIUI, systemd does its own cgroup management.

I haven't been able to find any documentation on how to do this, and every google search hit on the subject is either about some workaround, does not work, or is for some other linux distribution.

Comment: What is wrong with the solutions for "other linux distributions"? Do they not work on Ubuntu ?

Comment: They assume the existence of /etc/cgroup.conf and /etc/cgconfig.conf, neither of which exist on ubuntu and , if created, are ignored.

Comment: Sorry I do not know a better method perhaps file a bug report if the config files are ignored.

Comment: It turns out that `systemd` is simply broken in Ubuntu. In theory you should be able to run something like `systemd-run --user --pty -p MemoryMax=8G -p CPUWeight=10 google-chrome` but it doesn't work in reality because of bug https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/10581

Comment: I think config files `cg*` are used by `cgmanager` that is not compatible with `systemd` version that's used in Ubuntu. It used to work around Ubuntu 12.04 but since then `systemd` should take care of these things but it's still work-in-progress in reality.